# Python Pandas Dataframe Remove Rows by Timedelta Column Value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove rows from a dataframe that have a timedelta value of less than some number of seconds.

My dataframe looks something like this:

```
                  Start     Elapsed time
0   2018-10-29 07:56:20  0 days 00:15:05
1   2018-10-29 07:56:20  0 days 00:15:05
2   2018-10-29 08:11:25  0 days 00:00:02
3   2018-10-29 08:11:27  0 days 00:00:08
4   2018-10-29 08:11:27  0 days 00:00:08
5   2018-10-29 08:11:35  0 days 00:00:02
6   2018-10-29 08:11:37  0 days 00:00:00
```

I would like to remove all the rows where Elapsed time is less than some number of seconds - let's say 3 for now.  So I'd like a dataframe that looks like this (from the above):

```
                  Start     Elapsed time
0   2018-10-29 07:56:20  0 days 00:15:05
1   2018-10-29 07:56:20  0 days 00:15:05
3   2018-10-29 08:11:27  0 days 00:00:08
4   2018-10-29 08:11:27  0 days 00:00:08
```

I've tried a number of different things yielding a number of different error messages - usually incompatible type comparison errors.  For example:

```
df_new = df[df['Elapsed time'] > pd.to_timedelta('3 seconds')]
df_new = df[df['Elapsed time'] > datetime.timedelta(seconds=3)]
```

I'd like to avoid iterating over all of the rows, but if that's what I have to do then I'll do that.

Your help is very appreciated!

Edit: My real problem is that the dtype of my 'Elapsed time' column is object instead of timedelta.  A quick fix would be to cast the dtype using the code below, but a better fix would be to ensure that the dtype is not set to the object type in the first place. Thank you all for your help and comments.

```
df_new = df[pd.to_timedelta(df['Elapsed time']) > pd.to_timedelta('3 seconds')]
```

Comment: What do you have for `df.dtypes` ?

Comment: `Start           datetime64[ns]

Elapsed time            object`

Comment: @jpp When I calculate the elapsed time I just do `datetime_end - datetime_start`. And the error I get from my first solution is `Cannot compare type 'Timedelta' with type 'str'`.  This is so frustrating but thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3):

Getting data using pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+)

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')
df['Elapsed time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Elapsed time'])
```

You can use:

```
df[df['Elapsed time'].dt.total_seconds() > 3]
```

Output:

```
                Start Elapsed time
0 2018-10-29 07:56:20     00:15:05
1 2018-10-29 07:56:20     00:15:05
3 2018-10-29 08:11:27     00:00:08
4 2018-10-29 08:11:27     00:00:08
```

Comment: Yep, but from OP's comment the problem is upstream. Something OP has done has converted dtype from `timedelta` to `object`. They should try and fix that part of their workflow rather than patch it later.

Comment: Scott Boston I've been looking for that `read_clipboard` method since I joined SO. Thanks!

Comment: jpp is right - my datatype is not timedelta as I'd thought, it's an object. I need to fix that and then this may work.

Comment: @angmcg, Yep, as such there's nothing wrong with your first solution `> pd.to_timedelta('3 seconds')` once you make sure your series doesn't get converted to `object`.